# Why am i unable to infer type parameters from a class that implements an interface?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

**Background**

I have an interface that declares a single method whose return type depends on which type parameters are supplied to the interface.

```
interface Command<T, U = void> {
    execute(input: T): [U] extends [void] ? T | Observable<T>: T | U | Observable<T|U>;
}
```

I then have a utility type which should return the type parameters `T` and `U` for the supplied type.

```
type GetCommandParamTypes<T extends Command<unknown, unknown>> = 
    T extends Command<infer IO, infer A> ?
    [IO, A] :
    never;
```

**Problem**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwPICMDOBTKA3AhigGwwBo4IAzAXznKghDgHIoAPAKzUYG4BYAKH79gAOxhZyuAMYY4AYXohcwgCYAeACqkAqnAC8cbBGDKAfIn5xLcDCwySArmIAUIsI4BccdQEpPAbS0AXWsWMRU0OD9DY2CAfi84AB84VEwcfCINM091JLgdZNSsPEIMDTytE14%20SkE%20GABPMBkAcQwYeRBFFQAFXChcEHUmjDRymzDlCM7utXthAGthCAB3YVJ5pdXhEzN9CytciYxwuQUlNRFyLDgASSRSK5uAQTNYg8s-e9Jn4PcPuDCDDYLDVOr8SQEXBoCLDZrPGYXOCgMBEEAnGDTc4qVRoGBQEQAczMCDqVhCdkcGBcwjcME8eIJwkJvjgjKJeSK6VKuPxRJJAPJUHa9igwjI5BpdO81XJtRqdUh0NhIwAQoiVMjwGiMViukjeUzCaRhPYQCgbskAGLzSQwYAQHakgR8ck2SnOVweNl85ms9nMvKm82WuA24R2h3i53koUisXI2mOWVWeXyiFQmFeEayDXKcwut22ByepP0n1G1lckqZAPEguxqzCmCi8UUKWOGUAtOKzMRACywFsyjhGDzBYB7pL1K95brQbNFqg-t9hIXIageXDkcdeRQEAgRCUDcbcGbrcTdJTlh7LqVWcHw9H1YyY%20x%20ZROtEetmho5yWDJdSG3e1d2SfdDwwJQBULKwpypDs51XdclyrdBilfP9AwAxdQxAqM9wPI8dhPRtzwTdtZy7V1U34dMXQAegYuA2g6d8%20gGIYRjQOpGmaOA%20IwABGPQWPaPMOMGUcxjzLDiSqfgmMiOtSGiZRAl4kYBJGAAmUTWIk-opO41RZJUit%20QUvglL8cy6w0l1BO05oAGZ9PE9ijK45oZPfOSUKwUg612aobPnHCNyC1cHP4JzBIAFnctj9V6LzpNMvzwsBXCoGA21QJ2KywuQiKgLDfKoxi%20otMEgBWJLDM49KzNXE0cq3CrHRCxTmNs1rso3DqIwKqq4pGAA2BrPKakzRwRd8qjgJSbGaO0MHzPqjVUox1J65T%20vszT%20MEgB2KaUuUSTvNGDQ1TzRblpYVaxA28zALwzrhAc4qjQCzdrU%20qLftKj7hsqo6ZEEgAOc7Ziu9LR1zBauCW5iVrsF79q2gwdu%203q7JKlJ0O5WtVxMUaapGABOWGLnhkzH3WxHkdRkJnvWrH-wGsqIOIoady%20vbNq597-rgXmoPFAGwcdIGRfa8CiMl-mRoh5zhIABlp1KZp81RGZHEYX1Ke6Uce9nXsJ0XSAl49pYFvHOew7nQ1tqXypl9YLOd0XCMgu2PYFzliZrMost9xX-fd-CuocoA)

Although `GetCommandParamTypes` works as expected when supplied with the `Command` interface, i'm struggling to debug why i'm not getting the result i expected when supplying it with a class that implements that interface.

```
 type type1 = GetCommandParamTypes<Command<string>>;
// [string, void]

type type2 = GetCommandParamTypes<Command<string, string>>;
// [string, string]

type type3 = GetCommandParamTypes<Command<string | number, string>>;
// [string | number, string]

type type4 = GetCommandParamTypes<Command<string | number, Function>>;
// [string | number, Function]

type type5 = GetCommandParamTypes<Command<string, number | Function>>;
// [string, number | Function]

type type6 = GetCommandParamTypes<TypeACommand>; // expected [string, void]
// [string, string]

type type7 = GetCommandParamTypes<TypeBCommand>; // expected [string, number | Function]
// [string | number | Function, string | number | Function]

type type8 = GetCommandParamTypes<TypeCCommand>; // expected [string, void]
// [string, string | Observable<string>]

type type9 = GetCommandParamTypes<MixedTypeCommand>; // expected [string | number, boolean | Function]
// [string | number | boolean | Function, string | number | boolean | Function]

type type10 = GetCommandParamTypes<MixedTypeObservableCommand>; // expected [string | number, boolean | Function]
// [string | number | boolean | Function, string | number | boolean | Function | Observable<string | number | boolean | Function>]
```

**Question**

Should it be possible to infer type parameters from a Class that implements an interface or is there something wrong with my implementation?

Could someone please explain what happens when a Class is inspected to infer type parameters or point me in the direction of any resources that might help explain it?

**Update 1**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwPICMDOBTKA3AhigGwwBo4IAzAXznKghDgHIoAPAKzUYG4BYAKH79gAOxhZyuAMYY4AYXohcwgCYAeACqkAqnAC8cbBGDKAfIn5xLcDCwySArmIAUIsI4BccdQEpP6uAA%20cDpBqJg4%20EQagcEmvHyUgnwwAJ5gMgDiGDDyIIoqAAq4ULgg6mkYaNE2YipocgpKavbCANbCEADuwqQt7V3CJmb6Flb%20NRh1DXlNqiLkWHAAkkik84sAgmYA-KOWANorpBsAunDue3DCGNhY8Un8kgS4aPXl6Ru5%20cpwoGBEIEmMHqX1maBgUBEAHMzAgklZrLYHM5XB44ODIcIob50RDoTEwlg8IQMKoMdDYZcEVBsvYoMIyOQXMI3DBvPEEYkEkkni83hUAEKglS-cAAoEgxoisl4rGkYT2EAoRZBABiLUkMGAEEGcIEfARNjsjgwzNZnnJWJxlqhMQVSpVcHVwk12oZeoR1Np9N%20LMcHKsXK5j2ery8FVkwp%20esuRuRptRMAtsuxnkJERJMsxMPMBs9lhpMDpDIoZsc7MuQZ5ofqAFlgLZlO8MFHc7GkSay0ncdm7YrlVBrSm%20w6oDFna6dTEUBAIEQlLn8wXvQzEwHLFX9byw-XG8308SiK2-uLRJKZios-igvaB6QJ1qp0EZ3OMEpKfrDR2UX7uzaRwOOIHpEpL-je-aOg%20brTrO86DIuS6FsWjJdhWeYbvwwb6gA9NhcBZDkUrKEUJRlBUaBJKk6RwFRGAAIx6Ph2RRiRpTNlUUZXliQzxLhcD7DapCGMYJyURUNEVAATIxBEscUbHkaonGCT2FJxPwfECSmpA2qJ%20q0RJ6QAMwycxRGsWR6QcURXG2uBo46SmPEaXhWm9vZd6qVien8AZtEACymYRF7EfJlmVEpNlgVcEFQPeGqPoM6l8Jp0W3lg8UuolPnJOJtEAKxBXJpHsZFIW2fKsXjglbrOSlrkqelY5qjVOo5X5FQAGxFeZYWlc2nxEXEcB8TY6SahgPxudCQlGMoempdpXlQu1eUVAA7D1IUWf1gpRsNo0sONYhTY1VUtVlboLQ1S1pedTqtcIq3UbRAAcW3fDtinNpGQ1cCNeFjXYJ38SpwnzS5oO3cOoToESIG2SYz0yLRACcH1NF9VmqLuk0-X9AOIsdk1Q%205MUOXAL5wdVl1tZD01YgBGXLUzzWU7Bb4Mhdk5PWJL0VHRAAMGOFH1im402FTASS%203-YdxOnTD5OeVTnM0zz12k9eyvM3do4wa%20C7c4lBJwxmUR6wOBvU8btV6UAA)

If i remove the conditional type from the command return type (which is not the desired behaviour as the second type parameter is optional and i don't want `void` in the return type if it's not supplied) it does seem to get closer to what i was expecting. Or at least something a bit more workable.

```
interface Command<T, U = void> {
    execute(input: T): T | U | Observable<T | U>;
}
```

At first glance it appears that the `execute` method `input` type is being returned for `infer IO` and the return type is being returned for `infer A`.

But for `TypeACommand` that has the following signature:

```
execute(input: string): string | Observable<string>
```

`[string, string]` is returned, not `[string, string | Observable<string>]`

Where as `TypeCCommand` which has the following signature:

```
execute(input: string): Observable<string>
```

`[string, string | Observable<string>]` is actually returned instead of `[string, Observable<string>]`

And `MixedTypeObservableCommand` which also only has an `Observable` as the return type also returns all the type parameters of the `Observable<...>` and the `Observable` itself.

So:

```
execute(input: string | number): Observable<string | number | Function | boolean>
```

becomes:

```
[string | number, string | number | boolean | Function | Observable<string | number | boolean | Function>]
```

**Update 2**

This is a link to a previous working example i created, before also adding `Observable` to the return type of the `Command` interface.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCA5CA3CAnAPACoA0UAqgHxQC8UA2oQLpQQAewEAdgCYDO9nbHmYB%20clABcUQgG4AsAChFoSFADCAewC2WpDzjAArrk6FwEfAEFSAIRpQsGgJbcqtOjeZsOPfnUcuolCWksFQAD5QNvJKCk6cHLgAZqjQmjp63PgAkgDyZpCkltzcTsBOGpxICLmGwGB1BdC0Aa5QAN6KUN0srBAodRAAFPENwFJ5TQCUUum6%20hBGJk05%20eZFJWUVVTV1Y00UMQC%20isrmUADii3OZAApIuEhaTbxEvT586trzWYacANacDQAd04pD%20gJBnAobigXR6hHeXE%20Nx4%20HiSTwUDypAxWMsVBE8O6dBxsHgyDQmBwBAAoqwUAhDNwLNZsbkKKRWhRmBJiVBBDSYopGUhePwmpZUdwoE4tIgIFouMB%20NL8LxgLh4gBzKidWI9Xr9QYjThjKQarWcbUzKCWnUdfmG3CLYycWVmuoxQ0nBS%20kXIcVQACyTj63Ca0tl8oQiuVqu%20mXVmodkU4hi0ACM8KQAGJ-FDlSp604KQ1sY0cU3mu0p60RAUZ7O4W32%20tpptYyL5ziF7aOsuGnoupbu0Ze-m%20-0KUVB0PhyOJngAJmjCqVCQTGTRbe1DfTWZzUB7fcqDczGg0sb0JYNPQrAyr4-Gtate47h5bFrr78bn4bJ5Fu6kQXleEB6AOQ7Dq6JgemM3o9FOpYsqKLpQCglQagKWC4FIgp4DEKHIGhGGcFhWDcFIrSEf0xHQKRWGgQgUhMeBnA0ah9GYcAr7fm%20HF0eh3F-nhna4AJDxcWRPFJAWUiAdswoKERklCdJr65Lg6AZnxqZ-s2EkkcJlqadpWiaSeuntvpXbHgWQGGVJWEmVpGYWQWmk2JezGvnpB7NgB9n9iB3lsVAjlqYx3nub2LGhRB3ZBZUSkqUZ6kqBAUpLpR0jmFl27cBFDE8VoYYQBG5jSlI87lYuBVKQA9A1XwFQYbpNKWGXobgwAAIz2NKbXLOYyZvocUBNb51qKLGPEoD1vVSPNfX2JaSldctq60INMGmCNu5cs4rgyBNzW7jNizdcAy5LT1W2vut5zLQAzAN2VDXtkCjTqpD%20Xg42Tbu%205iRdc09c9t3AK9tAuWZj2qMtAAsb2tbtKxA4lvZAb9YkA2dP7A-%20mOnpwoNXYjkPIzDmqmW5uAnvD9E9QArCjPwfejP440TdlY9seNTb%20f24IFfOVGTy3M5DrPU7gtPmfTBaM1dABsbOZBz%200E8T2M2SLIVgTeJ2TYLhMBQb17AbzJMSz1KuQ2rsvyzFKCed5SmKJNVzANK9yPM85i8J15wZf1tDe77DxPC8%20BqruMLG81dAHQ4R2MGTSBSKH9jJ5qXLcIwysZfdEfZX70eB7H2XfdapDxwLudvodgRk5mWfmPdjf54XweqBl0OXNcZdRwHkCvHH2t63XP4J6d9AY1Pqctwos3oe3kAD438vd0X5hU4PPvD-7MeStKDcp606cr5dOUZfvXcOAXu%20QDLB%20R8flcT2%20ZtHgpxbn5PYWeYkqcCvqvCA68ICvy3q5LQpBZK9h7rELqGVHZvyPhXMe%20AaoVUgGfRO89AFiWAWLUBZMkiQLQTAsy8CCxILOH3cwAB2ewpcCrl1HhAV4OC6o-GXAA7%20H5mykFYgla2QEwGXW1JAlh7hYYZhEdFRWiCYhAA)

There at least appeared to be consistency in the types returned for `infer IO` and `infer A` for this version, where `IO` was the `execute` methods input type and `A` was the `execute` methods return type.

I was then able to use `Exclude` to calculate the corresponding types in relation to the `Command` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens if because when checking is `T` in `GetCommandParamTypes` is an instance of `Command` it doesn't actually check if the class you provided implements the interface. Typescript has structural, not nominal typings, so what it does is compare the signatures of `Command<..., ...>` and of `T`. Type `TypeACommand` has a signature

```
type TypeOfACommandObject = {
    execute(input: string): string | Observable<string>
}
```

There is nothing suggesting it implements `Command`, it is just an object that has a method `execute` with particular arguments and return types. If you now pass this object to `GetCommandParamTypes` you will find the exact same problem: you would probably expect the return type to be `[string, void]`, but it's actually `[string, string]`. And there is no contradiction, because `Command<string, string>` has signature

```
{
    execute(input: string): string | string | Observable<string | string>
}
```

Which is indistinguishable from the signature of `Command<string, void>`. So you cannot type it that easily.

The reason it will work correctly when you try `GetCommandParamType<Command<string, void>>`, even though the signature of `Command<string, void>` is as described above and you would probably expect it to be inferred incorrectly as well, is because of typescript's compiler implementation. I assume that when checking if type `T` is an instance of `Command` it first checks if `T` **is** `Command`. In this case it **is** literally and instance of `Command`, so it just skips comparing the structure and yields the correct type arguments. `TypeOfACommandObject` and `TypeACommand` however are not direct instances of `Command`, even though the latter implements it, so this shortcut fails. This is a speculation though, I'm not familiar with typescript implementation.

---

Speaking about fixing it, I can't really think of a good way without restructuring the return type of `execute` so that `T` and `U` are not merged. I could think of branded types like adding a special unique signature to return type of command using `unique symbol` type, but it will be very hard to use both when implementing `Command` and when using it outside. You should probably try to separate `T` and `U` somehow

---

UPD:

In the updated example it works because of the different definition of `GetCommandTypeParams`

```
type ReplaceNever<T, U> = [T] extends [never] ? U : T;

type GetCommandParamTypes<T extends Command<unknown, unknown>> = 
    T extends Command<infer IO, infer A> ?
    [IO, ReplaceNever<Exclude<A, IO>, void>] :
    never;
```

If you stick this same definition in the first example, you will find that it also almost works as expected, the only problem is the last class with `Observables`. So you'll need a small adjustment

```
type GetCommandParamTypes<T extends Command<unknown, unknown>> = 
    T extends Command<infer IO, infer A> ?
    [IO, ReplaceNever<A extends Observable<infer U> ? Exclude<U, IO> : Exclude<A, IO>, void>] :
    never;
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwPICMDOBTKA3AhigGwwBo4IAzAXznKghDgHIoAPAKzUYG4BYAKH4wAnmAxwAShjAFcAYwwA5DNiwAeACqkAqgD44AXjgBtdQF04GFjAwA7ACZpjN5VnMB+OFrgAuOOt4CfMA21lDkcmIAwvQguPYa2gZw2BDAdnoI-HDZFiwYsgCu1gAUwWBFvuoAlJVwAD6e9XComDj4RBpNugGU-IIiYgDiGDDRILH2AAq4ULgg6gNonZbW9o5jE3aqBTYA1jYQAO42pDv7RzY6eoZZOeq5qw5wG3FbweRYcACSSKTvnwBBPRuW7ZIw-UiSaQRJQqKCqAEPWxPFpYPCEDCqf5QOAADWBcAAoixZAQCnZMbjSD89L5iaTyZiAdSkDpSCk0jpzN5QXBnHCAv1RM0ksNRjFXtNZvNFqpMnwcrl8kUMKUbOUYL40DAoMEAOZNGwFEAoLA1ZroNHtTHa3U2A0NI0mz4NABiO1kMGAEBsTRQEAgRDiOn4lBDgX4pNwaEcC1EAJe9jgoGkGBAthg6wl8Vt+oyvMsypKZQqcFz9vN5YdFta6I6VfzCsVOSgIwKUF9FDVGqqAUVvT4A8jMhjfgGACFE3Zk+AiOmQlnxq84Koq6QnaacW6PV6fTp5YrC4Vi+rS1XKzr9YbjZumu6bJ7vb6D83sq2YO3fSWYH2cgOh3wUajnGGCRFOiAFnkx6qt+WqXhWviom0GKrvBeqNq+b5th2ZDkN2RS9ry-59IBI6OAAssAeR2CB4EvtkR4qvhmplmh17OlAF52tWG4unA96Pj6foBkGz68oq76fsmp4-kRoYkUBFFURgNEDEhdagdm04pnOGaLpsqHcexm6kAJu6+g0-qBhgwYQU2DFQUxsGsUZjo3macGuXAVmiU06nWoZeZ+ZayH1mxbkcXeO5PsJ1m2fRzaSThXbfoR9lwMREZ8AA9NlcBilOUpzCBaAkcIwrlRgACMoojIVMzFbKU6BfaVwBLlxhrskqR2KYZUDHAlUAEy1eKS5TA1MqiEszVdQ2OjtXlRhzWhfWBJVg0DAAzKN9XSiVqizeFfLuVApDzYtnXHbxZ0ufqa1CmIlUACy7VpRVTRgM1aS1PGnaZ0V7gt-Adct13-fxgM2A9fAbZVACsb3jXYH0HUd3HrqdUUPuZbUg0tXU3djgnQ-1FUDAAbEjmyo7KIEJlpwM5QTaHsj1MNwwMADs1OSpNB0gZOjOXWDGMnZF2440+HMDZVAAcvMTftdMDGBwv41dYscr1ZNPQMACciso-zsqUdRtHC3AGui1eEUmd5Ik2RZkNSz6Mvk6IVUAAxG7T02qGbKkgf5GJTgtVvM5rtvi-bPlO8T5lrUAA)

This solution has a couple of weirdnesses like you won't be quite able to extract types from classes that implement `Command<string | number, string | Function>` for example, but if you can live with it then it's fine

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I was in the process of adding an update to my question when you responded and had come to the same conclusion that whether or not `implements Command<...>` was present on the Class made no difference as to how it was examined.

Comment: Up until yesterday i had this working, but then added `Observable` to the returned type, at which point the errors/inconsistencies in the return values appeared. I'll add a link to that version in my post, but you can see that when the `infer IO` and `infer A` behaviour was consistent - as in `IO` returned the `execute` method input type and `A` returned the `execute` method return type - i was at least able to use `Exclude` to get the result i expected.

Comment: The updated variant isn't working because Observable isn't there, it's because of this `ReplaceNever<Exclude<A, IO>, void>` part. If you replace definition of `GetCommandParamTypes` in the updated example with the previous definition, there will be the same problem as before. You can use the same solution with a small adjustment for Observables as long as you are fine with some weird cases, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks again Alex, i've spent more time than i care to admit trying to get my head round this, so greatly appreciate you taking the time to look at it for me :)